# iOS7 Custom setMaximumTrack Image with UISlider doesn't show on the device

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7

I am using custom "`UISlider`" to show progress bar of `MPMoviePlayer`. Its working fine in `simulator` but when i run the same on device it does not apply the image which i provide instead it shows the default behaviour I am using the following code:

```
UISlider *slider;
[slider setMinimumTrackImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"progress_bar_active.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
[slider setMaximumTrackImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"progress_bar_background_upper.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[slider setThumbImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"thumb.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

It is just really strange.My device is `iPad 2(7.0.6)`,`iPad3(7.0.4)` and Xcode Version is `5.1.1`.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: check image name and extension with case sensitive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try add state `UIControlStateNormal` to `setMinimumTrackImage` and `setMaximumTrackImage`

```
[slider setMaximumTrackImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"progress_bar_background_upper.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```